# How to read .xlsx format file from Azure Blob using pandas without creating temporary file

Tags: python, pandas, azure, dataframe

Below is my code.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
account_url = "XXXXXX"
containerName      = "XXXXXX"
blob_name = 'Abc.xlsx'
storageKey         = "XXXXX"
connection_string = "XXXX"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=containerName, blob=blob_name)

blob = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text(encoding=None)
engine = 'xlrd'
df = pd.read_excel(io = blob, engine = engine)
```

When I run it, the code throws exception :

```
raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'

ValueError: Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should work. Did you try: df = pd.read_excel(io = blob, engine = 'xlrd')?

Comment: @mostaque-mallick , please see my answer and also do not forget [to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your problem to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Below code downloads using stream in memory without creating temp file and pandas read excel from the stream.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

containerName = "XXXX"
blob_name = 'Abc.xlsx'
connection_string = "XXXX"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(containerName, blob_name)
with BytesIO() as input_stream:
    blob = blob_client.download_blob().download_to_stream(input_stream)
    df = pd.read_excel(io=input_stream)
    print(df)
```

Answer (score -2):

data=pd.read_excel("C:\ex1.xlsx")
or
data=pd.read_excel(r"C:\ex1.xlsx") #if u r using Windows,some times requries

Comment: It's for offline file not for reading file from Azure